# Add row or textfield when Button tapped swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

i need help please. How to add new textfield on uiview or row in uitableview when my custom UIbutton on view is tapped. The scenario like contact app in iphone when user want to add new phone number.

[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jqjJ.png)

All content in row or textfield can be edited by user, and the data will be save if user tapped save button on navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reload tableview, you should use beginUpdates() and endUpdates() for tableview.It would be much better approach..

First of all append data in your tableview array on button click

```
Yourarray.append(" data")
```

Then update your table and insert new row

```
   tblname.beginUpdates()
    tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)
        ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tblname.endUpdates()
```

Comment: thanks, but that don't work and say error :"attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update"

Comment: oh sorry, your suggestion is work, i forgot to add numbers of row for section, thanks, but is possible to add empty cell to table? because i have custom cell there are textfield that always active for edit by user. example i want to add new number, than empty cell with textfield appears. when i tapped save the phone number is add to array.